# Read Date from excel using linqToExcel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to read Date from excel file but always I'm getting 01/01/0001:

```
 var empDetails = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<Réception_camions>(sheetName) select a;

foreach (var a in empDetails)
{
    if (a.Date_d_arrivée != null )
    {
        DateTime Date = (a.Date_d_arrivée);

        TimeSpan heure = (a.heure_d_arrivée);
        decimal Pd = a.Poids_cam;
        int Id_qualité = Convert.ToInt32(a.Id_qualité);

        int result = PostExcelData(Date, heure, a.Poids_cam, a.Id_cam, a.Id_qualité);
        //...
    }
}
public int PostExcelData(DateTime Date_d_arrivée, TimeSpan heure_d_arrivée, Decimal Poids_cam, int Id_cam, int Id_qualité)
{
    Réception_phosphateEntities DbEntity = new Réception_phosphateEntities();

    var InsertExcelData = DbEntity.usp_InsertNewEmployeeDetails1(Date_d_arrivée, heure_d_arrivée, Poids_cam, Id_cam, Id_qualité );

    return InsertExcelData;
}
```

In my excel file the type of the first column (Date) is Date. 
Can someone help me please?

Comment: instead of null use Db.Null.   You are trying to convert an empty cell to a date and getting the default date which is 1/1/1

Comment: the cell isn't empty, and it works for other fields,the problem is  just for Date and time.

Comment: Is the date and time in worksheet a string?  The culture for the date may be different than the culture of you PC settings.  VS will use the culture of your pc settings and if the date/time is a string you may have issues.

Comment: I did some modification and it's OK for the date but still the Time for `heure_d_arrivée` not working I got an error "'Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.TimeSpan'" ; In excel I use type "Date" for  `Date_d_arrivée` and `heure_d_arrivée`

Comment: So use DateTime instead of TimeSpan for the time.